# From xyz excel to 3d points

Tags: qgis, 3d

I have this

[image: kind of table]

and I'd like to get this kind of view

[image].

i.e. from xy, to get the z value in a 2d drawing and is it possible to get a full 3d view ?

I spent like 1 hour on internet but can't achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

QGIS is at present a 2D GIS program in terms of display. To view Y and Z as shown in your image you would have to replace the standard X, Y. At that point, the spatial components (and benefits) of the data is lost. You may be able to keep the X, Y, Z and use a profile tool, but the ones I've seen use a raster for input rather than a series of points.

Since you are already in Excel with your data (according to your title), I suggest you make a simple scatter plot using the Excel chart tools. Since this is a GIS forum, I won't go into details or discuss Excel 3D scatterplots.

For a 3D view in GIS, you can import the CSV to QGIS (Layer --> Add Layer --> Add Delimited Text Layer). Install the qgis2threejs plugin (Plugins --> Manage and Install Plugins --> enter in search bar and install). The plugin will appear under the Web menu in QGIS. This plugin uses JavaScript and WebGL to create a 3D website. The website is then viewed in a browser (Chrome or FireFox seem to do better than IE at present) - not in QGIS itself.

Expect to spend some time fiddling around. It can take longer than an hour to get accustomed to the software and work out the nuances.

Answer (score -2):

I think, you should just import csv file to GIS (Qgis or ArcGIS) and add Z values. Something like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkixWXu5jJE

Comment: Please summarize the main concept here, otherwise this answer might turn useless when the links break.